# Requisição HTTP React Native

Tags: react, react-native, http-request, request, xmlhttprequest

uma API envia um `status:false` o código pega `status`. Enquanto `status==false`, será renderizado a imagem de `exclamation.png` e mensagem `'Pedido em Análise'`. Caso `status` mude para `true` ambos valores de imagem e mensagem mudam(`check.png` e `'Pedido Aprovado!'`). Infelizmente não consigo, como faço para checkar se o `status` mudou para `true`?

Código no Expo >> https://snack.expo.io/@domxicote/teste

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export default class Exemplo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      image: require('./src/exclamation.png'),
      message: 'Pedido em Análise',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://recivida-dados.codeanyapp.com/response.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (responseJson.status) {
          this.setState({
            image: require('./src/check.png'),
            message: 'Pedido Aprovado!',
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={this.state.image} />
        <Text>
          {this.state.message}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
});
```

Comment: Você pode criar uma função que será executada em períodos de tempo como o setInterval do javascript. Usando o componentDidMount você só conseguirá executar essa sua função apenas 1 vez e não conseguirá ver se o status mudou.

Comment: Você pode implementar alguma coisa usando o Socket.io também, dê uma olhada em: https://github.com/vinnyoodles/react-native-socket-io-example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar mais ou menos assim

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => this.GetStatus(), 10000);
}

function GetStatus(){
  fetch('https://recivida-dados.codeanyapp.com/response.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
    if (responseJson.status) {
      this.setState({
        image: require('./src/check.png'),
        message: 'Pedido Aprovado!',
      });
    }
    else{
      //Do Something
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
}
```

Desse modo sua função será executada de 10 em 10 segundos e você poderá ver se o status ainda está false ou se mudou pra true